# Cannot parse characters from string in java

Tags: java, string, parsing, character, charat

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Out {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        String[] arr = new String[n];
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = input.next();
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
            System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(arr[i].replace(Character.toString(arr[i].charAt(arr[i].length() - 1)), "")));
            System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(Character.toString(arr[i].charAt(arr[i].length() - 1))));
            result += Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(arr[i].replace(Character.toString(arr[i].charAt(arr[i].length() - 1)), "")), Double.parseDouble(Character.toString(arr[i].charAt(arr[i].length() - 1))));


        }
        System.out.println(result);

    }

}
```

This code is supposed to get a string (e.g. 567) and raise 56 to the power of 7. It is NOT working only for the case when I have 212. I know it is very easy with arr[i]/10 and arr[i]%10. But I cannot understand the behavior here. I wanted to know why this solution is not working. Thank you!

Comment: I would at least simplify the code.  Lines like `Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(arr[i].replace(Character.toString(arr[i].charAt(arr[i].length() - 1)), "")), Double.parseDouble(Character.toString(arr[i].charAt(arr[i].length() - 1))))` are pretty unreadable.  Programs should be written to be understood by humans first, computers second.

Comment: Instead of replacing character, try to get a sub string from 0 n-1, which ignores the last character. If you replace so, the n-1th character will have "" and nth character will have end of string and that is causing you trouble, I guess.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. If you have only three input integers `m`, `n` and `e` (the exponent), wouldn't it be enough to print `Math.pow(10 * n + m, e)`?

Comment: @PaulBenn the problematic here is as follows: *Double.parseDouble(arr[i].replace(Character.toString(arr[i].charAt(arr[i].length() - 1)), ""))* results in *1.0* for input string *212* when *21.0* is expected. Also the count of input integers is dynamic based on the first input. Each of the following integer values are in the kind MN, where length(MN) >= 2, length(M) >= 1, and length(N) = 1.

Comment: please use move variables - it will help a lot (also have a look at the `String.substring` methods - `replace` is probably not what you want) and it is working well for (small) numbers without repetition.

Answer (score 3):

String.replace will not work here. This function replaces all occurrences of the character in the string.

So for a number like 212, "212".replace("2", "") will result in "1".

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-

Consider using substring:

```
String s = "212"
System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1)); //prints 21
System.out.println(s.substring(s.length()-1)); //prints 2
```

Comment: For printing out the last character as string it could be used *s.substring(s.length() -1)*.

Comment: Yes that is perhaps more readable, edited my answer with your suggestion.